# Spring boot and Weblogic Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem deployment issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am updating application to avoid latest log4j vulnerability and rewriting our application to use logback instead of log4j. Local development I use tomcat and it works perfectly fine but when I deploy the same war file to weblogic I am getting the following error which never got using the same code before.

I am using latest springboot.

Error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.spring.boot.Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013427/weblogic-12c-centralized-log4j-or-logback-configuration
It seems that Weblogic has a dependency on org.apache.logging.log4j.* and needs to included in your project.

Comment: Welcome @JavaSpringDev.  Check WL shared lib folder. You may need to add manually.